# How can I define a repeater template that spreads into 'n' columns per 'z' items in each column?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, itemtemplate

I have a `List<string>` with country names as items in it.

```
List<string> myCountries;
```

I want to bind this list as a datasource to an asp.net Repeater.

What I want to achieve is to define a template within my repeater so that it binds the country names into columns side by side and limit each column to have maximum 5 countries.

Basically it has to start binding on the very left column and when there is 5 countries bound it should add a new column on the right and go on binding in this new column. After 5 more countries it should again add one more column and go on like this.

How can I achieve this?

***Countries:***

- country 1 + country 4 + country 7 +
- country 2 + country 5 + country ..+
- country 3 + country 6 + country n +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether repeater is having property repeatcolumn repeatrow and repeatDirection property.

but datalist can do your job..

Comment: Thanks Bindas, I did not know this property exist on DataList!